# Integrate: the integral is probably divergent

Tags: r, numerical-integration

I was doing some integration into a loop using `integrate` and I come up with an error I can't understand neither get rid of. Here is a MWE I could extract:

```
u_min = 0.06911363
u_max = 1.011011 
m = 0.06990648
s = 0.001092265
integrate(f = function(v){pnorm(v, mean = m, sd = s, lower.tail =  FALSE)}, u_min, u_max)
```

this returns an error "the integrale is probably divergent" which is obviously false. I tried to modify the parameters a little bit and got this working for example:

```
u_min <- 0.07
u_max <- 1.1
m <- 0.0699
s <- 0.00109
integrate(f = function(v){pnorm(v, mean = m, sd = s, lower.tail =  FALSE)}, u_min, u_max)
```

I tried to have a look into the `integrate` function with `debug`but it's a wrapper of a `C`code. Also I'm not a specialist of quadrature techniques. I saw this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15892586/solving-an-integral-in-r-gives-error-the-integral-is-probably-divergent) but couldn't make anything from it.

thanks

Comment: From `?integrate`: `Like all numerical integration routines, these evaluate the
     function on a finite set of points.  If the function is
     approximately constant (in particular, zero) over nearly all its
     range it is possible that the result and error estimate may be
     seriously wrong`. Your function is basically always 0.

Comment: @nicola So what would one do to not get an error returned? How would I be able to work around this?

Comment: @Plinth you have to narrow the interval around values where the function is not zero, see nicola's answer below

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The default tolerance of `.Machine$double.eps^0.25` (= 0.0001220703) needs to be lowered.  Try, for example, this:

```
f <- function(v) pnorm(v, mean = m, sd = s, lower.tail =  FALSE)
integrate(f, u_min, u_max, rel.tol = 1e-15)

## 0.0009421867 with absolute error < 1.1e-17
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd use this work-around:

```
integrate(f = function(v){pnorm(v, mean = m, sd = s, lower.tail =  FALSE)}, 
      max(u_min,m-10*s),min(u_max,m+10*s))$value  + (u_min-m+10*s)*(u_min<m+10*s)
```

What I've done:

- `pnorm` with `lower.tail=FALSE` is basically zero when very far on the right from the mean. So there is no point in "stretching" the right limit of the integral. So, when `u_max > m+10*s`, you just integrate to `m + 10*s`. You can of course change the `10` factor to add precision;
- on the other hand, on the left `pnorm` is basically always 1; so you can enhance the left limit and the missing part is just `u_min - m+10*s`. Same logic as above.

Comment: this is indeed a good trick I didn't get that the interval length could alter the result of the estimation